# watir - file_field not working when running on server

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cucumber, watir

I am currently writing features to upload an image using the file exploer in ie. 
Locally this works fine and opens the file explorer and locates the image without any problems. However when i run it as part of the acceptance run ont he server it self it fails to open the file explorer, It will just sit there waiting for it, it doesnt even time out at the usual 60 seconds so i assume something is trying to happen behind the scenes but is failing silently.

Has anyone had this issue and found a fix or work around for it?

Comment: what OS is the server running?

Answer (score 0):

Most servers have IE very locked down by default since very little browsing is typically done from servers, and the browser itself represents a significant attack surface.  See here for more info [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537180(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The result is that unless you disable this enhanced security there are a number of things that just flat out won't work.  If you are running your test from the same server where the website is installed, then you will need to disable all the enhanced security stuff on IE.

This would be a violation of best practices for a production system, but is an understandable expedient for a test system as an alternative to having a pair of systems with different OS's (client and server) for your testbed and running the tests on the client. (more realistic, but requires another system or VM be created and maintained)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I worked out specifically what was happening with the security after a while. For my watir tests to run onthe server ie has to started in administrator mode which works fine, but when ie opens up the file browser it is NOT being opened in administrator mode hence the watir scripts cant attach to it or control it. The work around i found for it is to use firewatir and firefox on the sever to run them. Thats works like a treat.

Comment: @lambsubstitute,  For what it's worth, I find that on Server 2008R2  I need to run Watir (or call my cucumber features, which have steps written using Watir) from a command line that is opened in Administrator mode.   I don't know if that would make a difference for you.  So far none of my tests have required me to do file operations, but I expect that to change eventually ;-)

Comment: After revisiting this problem i finally worked out what the problem was. Because we were kicking our tests off using hudson and also because hudson was the out of the box solution, it was not using the administrator rights from the account that was kicking it off. The solution was so simple, it was purely a matter of going to the hudson.exe, right clicking and in properties setting the always start as admin. Such a simple solution but it eluded me for so long. Anyway just thought  i would share my progress. Next step is to apply this fix to my other build server.

Comment: Thanks for the followup..   There's a few OS's where watir really has to run as Admin or it just won't work right, (hence my question/comment on your question above)  I'm guessing the system that is hosting Hudson is one of those OS's..